# Two-factor authentication with Kubuntu screensaver

Tags: kubuntu, kde, lightdm, lock-screen

I have been using Two-Factor Authentication with great success on Ubuntu 16.10 and then 17.04. The integration with Unity was flawless. The other day I upgraded to 17.10 and since Unity is on it's way out and the design of Gnome does not suit me, I've decided to move to KDE.

For login, I am still using LightDM without issue. But if I lock my screen, when I try to unlock it I get greeted by what I believe is kscreenlocker_greet and it does not seem to support 2FA. Does anyone know of a way to make kscreenlocker_greet support 2FA or to change the screen lock of KDE to something that supports it?